# Celery + Redis backend: How to limit queue size?

Tags: python, redis, celery, celeryd

Is there a way to limit queue size when I run [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) with [Redis](https://redis.io) backend?

Something like [x-max-length](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html) in queue predeclare for [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know that is not possible with Redis as backend.

Comment: Seems to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for prefetch limits in celery. Check it out [docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits).

Comment: The prefetch limit is a limit for the number of tasks a worker can reserve for itself. I need to limit my queues.

Comment: That's interesting! Limiting a queue for executing the task, I haven't come across anything like that before. Please do share if you find out the way for the same.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit hacky but you could try using a Redis lock when calling the task. That way if another process wants to call the task, it would have to wait for the Redis lock to be released (this would happen when either the task is done running or when the timeout is reached). This would prevent too many tasks being added to the queue

```
 with r.lock(some_lock_name, blocking_timeout=10):
    your_celery_task.delay()
```